# undefined reference to `sec_set_context' during mpi4py install

Tags: mpi, mpi4py

I am installing mpi4py using pip using the command pip3 install mpi4py, on a centos7 system.

I get this error:

```
/glade/u/apps/ch/opt/openmpi/4.0.5/intel/19.0.5/bin/mpicc _configtest.o -L/glade/u/apps/ch/opt/python/3.7.9/gnu/9.1.0/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/glade/u/apps/ch/opt/python/3.7.9/gnu/9.1.0/lib -o _configtest
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /opt/pbs/lib/libpbs.so.0: undefined reference to `sec_set_context'
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
error: Cannot link MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
----------------------------------------
```

Does anybody have any tips?

Comment: Are there other libraries in `/opt/pbs/libs`? It looks like you're forgetting to link something, and that has nothing to do with MPI.

Comment: There sure are: check out that warning: `/opt/pbs/lib/libpbs.so.0: undefined reference to `sec_set_context'`  -- I don't have a lot of experience with PBS  sounds like maybe OpenMPI expects some PBS libraries that are not already in user11328's environment?

Comment: It's annoying that your installation deletes the offending source otherwise I'd say try building it by hand. You can also run `nm` on libpbs.so. See what library references are missing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case on Cheyenne's HPC cluster, you will likely need to add these arguments to your compilation/link commands `-L/opt/pbs/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/pbs/lib -lsec` or reload the `ncarcompilers` module.

Nevertheless, I recommend you reach out to CISL's helpdesk at NCAR for any similar problems you encounter on our system as there are dedicated teams of people to help users resolve issues like this.